# Why can't a function in a namespace see my operator<< defined globally?

Tags: c++, c++14, name-lookup

I've defined an `operator<<` output function for `std::pair` instances, for use by some unit tests that want to print the values if they don't watch what's expected.  My test code also has pairs that are held as members of another class that has its own `operator<<` — specifically `boost::optional`, but for the sake of example I've defined a simple `Container` class here instead.  The problem is that the `operator<<` for `std::pair` values doesn't seem to be visible within the `operator<<` of the container class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, std::pair<T1, T2> const &pair) {
  return out << "{ " << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << " }";
}

namespace {

  template <typename T>
  struct Container {
    T value;
  };

  template <typename T>
  std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, Container<T> const &container) {
    return out << container.value;  // Error!
  }

}

int main() {
  std::pair<char, int> pair { 'a', 1 };
  Container<std::pair<char, int>> container { pair };

  std::cout << pair << std::endl;
  std::cout << container << std::endl;
}
```

The line near the end that outputs the plain pair works fine.  But when trying to output the pair within the container, the compiler can't find the `operator<<` for pairs.  Here's the message from GCC:

```
test.cc: In instantiation of ‘std::ostream& {anonymous}::operator<<(std::ostream&, const {anonymous}::Container<T>&) [with T = std::pair<char, int>; std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]’:
test.cc:28:16:   required from here
test.cc:18:16: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘const std::pair<char, int>’)
     return out << container.value;
            ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

…followed by a long listing of all the candidate `operator<<` functions that were considered, and why each one isn't suitable (because they're all for different types of values).  My template for `std::pair` is not in the list.

(This message is from Debian's GCC 6.3.0 with `-std=c++14`.  I get the same error, with different wording, from Debian's Clang 3.8.1-24 with `-std=c++14`, and Apple's Clang 1000.11.45.5 (Apple LLVM 10.0.0) with `-std=c++17`.)

If I remove the anonymous namespace around my `Container` template and its `operator<<`, the error goes away.  But that's not really a solution, since in reality the container is `boost::optional`, which of course is in namespace `boost`, and I can't change that.

It's not clear to me *why* my global `operator<<` isn't visible from within the namespace, since global scope should be part of the search path for unqualified lookup.  My best guess is that it's because my `operator<<` is a template, and templates don't seem to be part of the initial unqualified lookup, so ADL kicks in and finds a bunch of other `operator<<` functions defined in `std::` and as members within `std::ostream`, so the lookup stops there.  The list of candidate functions (in the compiler's error message) seems to be consistent with that interpretation.  But then it's unclear why it *does* work when the container is not in a namespace.

Is there a way to make this work without modifying the `Container` class?

---

(As background: I'm using the Boost.Test library and writing lines like `BOOST_TEST(some_func() == boost::make_optional(std::make_pair('a', 1)))`, where `BOOST_TEST` does some macro/template magic to extract the two sides of the expression and output their values if they don't match.  That requires the values to have an `operator<<` defined.  Boost provides one for `optional`, and I've written one for the `std::pair` within it, but the call from the former to the latter is where the problem lies.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unqualified lookup goes up one level at a time and stops as soon as it finds something. It finds an `operator<<` within the anonymous namespace - the very one you are calling from - and stops dead right there.

Consider wrapping an element of the `pair` or the `pair` itself into a wrapper in your own namespace. Then you can define an `operator<<` to do whatever you want and have it picked up by ADL.

Comment: Aha.  I'd noticed that my namespaced `operator<<` was in the list of candidates reported by the compiler, but didn't recognize the implication of that.  :-)  So unqualified lookup finds the namespaced one, but it doesn't match what's needed, so ADL goes and finds some more, but they don't match either, and it ends there.  Makes sense.

Comment: Since `operator<<` implementations typically work by calling others, this is really a general issue: the target function has to be either in the same namespace as the caller, or findable by ADL.  Parent namespaces don't work because the caller's existence blocks the lookup from going there.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make this work without modifying the Container class?

Yes. You have to put the  `operator<<` inside the namespace.

[DEMO](https://godbolt.org/z/DbYjT-) here.

Search for operator `<<` is only happening within the namespace `container.value` is defined in. [Related Post](http://Why%20doesn't%20ADL%20find%20function%20templates?).

Comment: That works, but since the container is really `boost::optional`, that'd mean defining my `operator<<` in namespace `boost`, which seems dirty.  (Pairs have nothing to do with Boost).  And then it won't be found when trying to output a raw pair, not in a container (since `boost` is not an inline namespace).

Comment: Alternatively I could define it in namespace `std` where ADL is looking, but [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) says that's not allowed.

Comment: Some exceptions are allowed if they are specializations. Would you be able to modify your operator << to allow for this?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `std` doesn't have an `operator<<` template that can accept a `std::pair`, so there's nothing to specialize.

Comment: Okay. Let's see if someone can come up with a better idea for your question.